# Setting to the header of express req object is not being retained across routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, routes

I am trying to set sessionId in my `req` object of express to be used across other routes. When I set it via middleware it works, If try the same via a route, it doesn't work.

I am trying to make the route approach to work because I am trying to set a 'sessionId' in my `req` object, this sessionId is based on userName. Hence I would like the route approach to work.

Instead of `req` object, I tried using `res.locals` but I am facing the same issue. What am I missing here ?

When I say it doesnt work, I meant that if I try to access `req.headers.sessionid` in some other route, it is `undefined`.

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const setSessionId = require('./setSessionId');

app.use(function(req, res, next){ // this works...
    const { username } = req.body;
    req.headers.sessionid = crypto.createHash("sha256").update('Temp Name').digest("hex"); // to be replaced by corpId;
    next();
})
app.use('/login',setSessionId);
```

**setSessionId.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const crypto = require('crypto');

router.post('/success', (req, res) => { // this doesnt work...
    const { username } = req.body;
    req.headers.sessionid= crypto.createHash("sha256").update(username).digest("hex"); // to be replaced by corpId;
    res.send(req.headers.sessionid);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Not sure, but the descriptions you've provided differ from the source code. Middlewares are request scoped. If you need to store values across the session try to use cookies or cache (e.g. redis) if you are planning for a stateless architecture.

Comment: i dont understand what you meant by "Not sure, but the descriptions you've provided differ from the source code. "; @kmos.w

Comment: Basically my requirement is store across the session but not in cookie or cache but in the 'req' object provided by 'express'

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue, you don't want to use cookies neither cache but you need to track resources across multiple requests. May I suggest that you rely upon HTTP custom headers?

**How**

First, write the request interceptor middleware `function` to check if the custom header is present. Append if it does not. Then write the response interceptor `function` to append the custom heade.

**E.g.**

```js
// request interceptor middleware function to append custom header.
// **Note** By convention, custom header starts with "X-"
// visit: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6648
const interceptReqForSessionId = (req, res, next) => {
  req.headers['X-Session-ID'] =
     req.headers['X-Session-ID'] ||
     crypto.createHash("sha256").update(username).digest("hex");
  next();
};

// response interceptor middleware function to append custom header.
// Client will be required to pass this header in the subsequent requests
const interceptResForSessionId = (req, res) => {
  res.header('X-Session-ID', req.headers['X-Session-ID'])
     .send(req.data);
};
```

Next, use the register the interceptors before and after the appropriate routes.

```js
router.post(interceptReqForSessionId, (req, /*res*/_, next) => {
  // rest of your code... req.headers[X-Session-ID] gives you the ID
  // do not return result immediately. Call next
  next();
}, interceptResForSessionId);
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for the effort, but we don't want the client to pass the header in each and every request. that's why we are trying to setting something in the req object and be done with it.
Long story short, setting the sessionId in req object should be a one time operation.

Comment: After some digging , I found the solution I wanted. I am using req.app.locals to persist my info across routes. Again, thank you for the effort @kmos.w